# Downloading a File from Expressr with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, react-router

I have this route on my server.js

```
app.get('/api/users/download/:id', auth, admin, (req, res) => {
  const file = path.resolve(".") + `/uploads/${req.params.id}`;
    res.download(file)
})
```

And this is a part of my component in React (using CRA)

```
class AddFile extends Component {
          showFileList = () => (
                this.state.files ?
                    this.state.files.map((item,i)=>(
                        <li key={i}>
                            <Link to={`/api/users/download/${item}`} target="_blank">
                                {item}
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                    ))
                :null
            )
}

    render() {
        return (
          <div>
             {this.showFileList()}
           </div>
          );
    }
export default AddFile;
```

Theses are some of my routes

```
const Routes = () => {
  return(
    <Layout>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin/add_file" exact component={Auth(AddFile, true)}/>
        <Route component={Auth(PageNotFound)}/>
      </Switch>
    </Layout>
  )
}
```

When I click on the li item it takes me to the 404 not found route, when it should take me to the route I'm handling in Express and download the file,BUT clearly is caught by react router first and displays me the "Not Found" page I have created,can it be something related to the proxy on package.json?

```
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000"
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

Some testing (https://codesandbox.io/s/8ykx3j88v0) shows that you can use

- `<Link to="/some-file" download target="_self">..</Link>`
- a regular `<a href="/some-file" download>...</a>`

Comment: I doesnt work, the browser "downloads a file" (not taking me to a new route like before though) but with a message something like: "Error: no files". Also, the route in express is not triggered (its not showing my console.logs). Looks like it still being handled in the browser, because it downloads an empty file instead of the file from the server.

Comment: @R.Romero open the developer tools in your browser, go to the Network tab and then click on the button in your app and see if a network request is registered on the Network tab. If nothing registers there then it is handled by the react/browser. If on the other hand it appears then the issue is with the backend (*check the url that is logged if it is the correct and check if it completes or if it fails*)

Comment: It works now, I think it was something related to the proxy of Create React App, I moved my project to a newer version (v2+) and setup the proxy using the http proxy middlware library in a file called setupProxy.js with the following: const proxy = require('http-proxy-middleware');
module.exports = function(app) {
  app.use(proxy('/api/', { target: 'http://localhost:5000/' }));
};  it now works thank you btw!

Comment: @R.Romero glad you got it sorted out.

Comment: This only works with resources from the same domain.